# How to add a network (IP) printer using command line or a script?

Tags: windows-7, script, network-printer

My company will be deploying a bunch of laptops that will be used during a seminar for people to sign up for services on our website.  At the end of the signup process they will need to print out a confirmation page.

We have a deployment tool (KACE) that will load a fresh copy of Windows 7, set the IE home page to what it needs to be, etc and I am looking for a way to set up a network printer using the command line, a batch file or a script so we don't have to do the setup manually on every computer as that would take a long time.

The printer is a Konica Minolta network copier and it needs to be set up as a local printer using a tcp/ip port.

I've found a couple vbscript files that are supposed to do this but I inevitably get errors when I try to make them work for me.

I have also tried to use `prnport.vbs`, but I can't even get past the first step of creating a tcp/ip port:

```
cscript c:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnport.vbs -a -r IP_192.168.1.5 -h 192.168.1.5
```

returns:

```
Unable to create/update port IP_192.168.1.5 Error 0x80041008 Invalid parameter
```

I've tried using different port names but always get this error.

Can someone help me figure out how to accomplish this?

Comment: Cscript's Prnport.vbs is definitely what you want. Are you on a domain? It's possible that this is a permissions issue, in which case you would use the appropriate username/password values after the -u and -w flags respectfully.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error as you until I tried this:

```
cscript c:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnport.vbs -a -r IP_192.168.1.5 -h 192.168.1.5 -o raw
```

The source "http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t514172-adding-printing-ports-and-printers-systematically-on-x64-windows-2003-r2.html" for the answer reads:

> When the IP does not exist or not yet on the network, you will need to 
>   specify the protocol and LPR queue name for the device. If the device is 
>   not included in tcpmon.ini you may also need to pass in the device 
>   configuration to the script.

The results of this command that I got were:

> Created/updated port IP_192.168.1.5